# Is there a way to get four square users twitter id using foursquare API

Tags: api, foursquare

**Is there a way to get four square users twitter id using foursquare API**

I have checked the gnip API, i have contacted them but the said it only supports enterprises

I need the users twitter id who checkin to specific locations using Foursquare so i can allow my users to communicate with them on my website

I need Anonymous users data and specifically not my friends data

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look at the Four Square API's documentation for a good place to start](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/users)... It appears that this information is potentially available, however it might be dependent on you being "friends" with them or not:

> If the user is a friend, contact information, Facebook ID, and Twitter handle and the user's last checkin may also be present.

[The `users` endpoint will return a user object:](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/user) This is available in their Compact and Complete objects, but not their "Mini" object.

> contact: An object containing none, some, or all of twitter, facebook, email, and phone. Both are strings.